# Minimum number of vertices in a binary tree of height 5

Tags: data-structures

What is the Formula to Find the minimum number of vertices required to make a binary tree (not a complete binary tree) of height 5 ?

Comment: I know that the answer is 5 ,with atleast one vertex in each level .  Am I right in this sense?

Answer (score 1):

A binary tree's height cannot be bigger than the number of nodes or vertices in the tree. So yes, the minimum number of vertices required for a binary tree of height 5 will be 5. Also, there must be n-1 edges between them. You can imagine a single series of connected nodes, and that is basically what you get.

Alternately, a full binary tree is a binary tree in which each internal vertex has exactly two children.This means a binary tree with n internal vertices has 2n + 1 vertices, 2n edges, and n + 1 leaves.

Comment: Why is it useful to note stats about a binary tree in terms of the number of internal nodes? Given the question, wouldn't it make more sense to put those in terms of the height instead?

Answer (score 1):

the minimum number of vertices in a binary tree of height n (with no further constraints) is always n.

proof:

1. if there were less than n nodes, the tree wouldn't be a valid binary tree (I guess I don't need to further explain this point)
2. if there were more than n nodes, it means at least one of the nodes has a brother (pigeonhole principle), which could be taken off the tree and it would  result in a valid, smaller binary tree, so we know that this tree is not minimal, which opposes our assumption of a minimal tree.
   -> a binary tree T is minimal -> T has n nodes